# Facial detection with Google Vision API shows over VideoView

Tags: android, android-camera, android-videoview, android-vision

I've been using the Vision API from Google Play Services in my app, and all works fine in my devices (Nexus 7 2012 with Android 5.1, and a cheaper tablet with android 4.2.2), but not in some of the production devices.

We have the vision api with the face detection framework running all the time our app is open, so the app changes content when the face detection detects him.

The problem is when we show some video with a `VideoView` at the same time that the face detection is working, because we have noticed that some kind of "ghost" appears on top of the `VideoView`, and we have seen that this "ghost" it's the preview that the face detection is getting in realtime.

It's complicated to explain, so we have recorded a video that illustrates the problem better: [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z0MIwSwLlHo&feature=youtu.be)

At this time, I have tried this stuff:

- Changing the dimensions of `.setRequestedPreviewSize(int, int)` , and we have seen that based on this dimensions, the "ghost" changes it's dimension too, so we realized that the preview size it's the one that was causing the problem.
- Removing the call of `.setRequestedPreviewSize(int, int)` from the `CameraSource.Builder` we have seen that internally, it defaults it's dimensions to 1024x768, as you can see on [`CameraSource`](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/blob/master/visionSamples/barcode-reader/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/vision/barcodereader/ui/camera/CameraSource.java) so the "ghost" fills the entire screen with this.
- Trying another framework to play the video, removing `VideoView` and using another based in `TextureView` doesn't helps too, the ghost it's still showing.
- Using different video formats doesn't helps too

I think this can be some kind of problem when more than SurfaceView or SurfaceTexture works at the same time, one on top of another, but this is the first time I have been working with a multimedia oriented app.

Somebody has some idea of what can be the problem?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Just to clarify Im posting the code Im using.

This is the method I am using in the app is being showed in the video:

```
private void setupFaceDetector() {
        Log.d(TAG, "setupFaceDetector");
        faceDetector = new FaceDetector.Builder(this)
                .setProminentFaceOnly(true)
                .setClassificationType(FaceDetector.ALL_CLASSIFICATIONS)
                .build();
        if (!faceDetector.isOperational()) {
            retryIn(1000);
        } else {
            faceDetector.setProcessor(new LargestFaceFocusingProcessor(faceDetector, new FaceTracker(this)));
            if (BuildConfig.FLAVOR.equals("withPreview")) {
                mCameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(this, faceDetector)
                        .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)
                        .setRequestedPreviewSize(320, 240)
                        .build();
            } else {
                mCameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(this, faceDetector)
                        .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)
                        .build();
            }
        }

    }
```

Im using a flavor to play with different kind of things, this project was only to be able to make the test of this feature easier.

When the `onResume()` method is called, Im loading the video from `File` and starting the `CameraSource` instance

```
private void initializeVideo() {
  mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
      mp.start();
    }
  });

  mVideoView.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
      Log.d(TAG, "Error playing the video");
      return false;
    }
  });
  mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
      playVideo();
    }
  });
}

private void startCameraSource() {
  try {
    mCameraSource.start();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Just to clarify:

- We are using FaceTracker just to detect faces, and using it's `public
  void onNewItem(int id, Face face)` and `public void
  onMissing(Detector.Detections<Face> detections)`
- The xml layout to show the `VideoView` is:

  ```
  <VideoView
      android:id="@+id/videoView"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="3"/>

  <ScrollView
      android:id="@+id/scroll"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1">

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/tv_log"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
  </ScrollView>
  ```

Comment: Can you include more details on how you are displaying the video?  Are you using the CameraSourcePreview from the samples along with some other view that is also displaying the video?

Comment: Thanks for your response @pm0733464, I have added some code about this sample. Im not using CameraSourcePreview from samples, just FaceDetector, CameraSource, and the VideoView.

Thanks for the help ;)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not quite sure, but here are some suggestions of things to try:

There is an open source version of CameraSource here that you can use and modify as needed in your app:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/blob/master/visionSamples/barcode-reader/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/vision/barcodereader/ui/camera/CameraSource.java

This has a couple of surface instance variables, mDummySurfaceView and mDummySurfaceTexture, that are used in working with the camera preview in the case that there is no display for the preview.  These get set up here:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/blob/master/visionSamples/barcode-reader/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/vision/barcodereader/ui/camera/CameraSource.java#L346

I'm guessing that in your app these dummy surfaces are somehow interfering with your video.  You might see if your app could use an alternate strategy for working with the camera that doesn't require these dummy surfaces.

You could also start the camera source with a specific SurfaceHolder that you supply, as is supplied here:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/blob/master/visionSamples/barcode-reader/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/vision/barcodereader/ui/camera/CameraSource.java#L370

You might try experimenting with creating alternative surfaces, and see if there's a way to avoid interference with your video.

If none of that works, you could also try writing camera controlling code yourself, similar to what CameraSource provides, but using the newer "camera2" API (we shipped CameraSource using the "camera1" API because at the time, this API had a little bit better backward compatibility with older cameras, but this has been improving with camera2).  If you do this, you can take a similar approach to passing preview images to a detector, as is done here:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/blob/master/visionSamples/barcode-reader/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/vision/barcodereader/ui/camera/CameraSource.java#L1191

Comment: Hi @pm0733464, I was not able to solve this, it's just one device the one that has this problem, Im starting to think that it's some kind of hardware problem, (but i really dont know if this can be a cause for this interferences).

I was able to run the face detection fine in some Nexus devices, and another ones with success, but not in the production device.

But I really appreciate your help and time :)